# Android HCE behavior is different with and without SIM

Tags: android, smartcard, rfid, hce, pcsc

I am developing an android HCE Application.

This is my simple code.

```
public class HceHostApduService extends HostApduService {

@Override
public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] apdu, Bundle extras) {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new byte[] {(byte) 0x90, (byte) 0x00};
}

@Override
public void onDeactivated(int reason) {
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("onDeactivated : %d", reason));
}
```

Test Case without SIM

```
  18 : send RF  : RF Off
  19 : recv RF  : RF Off OK
  20 : send RF  : RF On
  21 : recv RF  : RF On OK
  22 : send RF  : REQA
  23 : recv RF  : 000400
  24 : send RF  : ANTI-COLLISION
  25 : recv RF  : 0008FA07F0
  26 : send RF  : SELECT[08FA07F0]
  27 : recv RF  : SAK : 0020
  28 : send RF  : RATS[FF]
  29 : recv RF  : 000578807002
  30 : send PCSC: Connect
  31 : recv PCSC: 3B781800005350000010079000
  32 : send RF  : 0A0000a4040007A0000004520001
  33 : recv RF  : FA0001
  34 : send RF  : FA0001
  35 : recv RF  : FA0001
  ...
  55 : recv RF  : FA0001
  56 : send RF  : FA0001
  57 : recv RF  : FA0001
  58 : send RF  : FA0001
  59 : recv RF  : 0A009000
```

Test Case with SIM

```
  60 : send RF  : RF Off
  61 : recv RF  : RF Off OK
  62 : send RF  : RF On
  63 : recv RF  : RF On OK
  64 : send RF  : REQA
  65 : recv RF  : 000400
  66 : send RF  : ANTI-COLLISION
  67 : recv RF  : 000102663A
  68 : send RF  : SELECT[0102663A]
  69 : recv RF  : SAK : 0020
  70 : send RF  : RATS[FF]
  71 : recv RF  : 000B7877B402806453430430
  72 : send PCSC: Connect
  73 : recv PCSC: 3B781800005350000010079000
  74 : send RF  : 0A0000a4040007A0000004520001
  75 : recv RF  : 
  76 : recv RF fail : 0x02
```

If run without sim, wait 500ms.

If run with sim, don't wait and disconnected.

Why are these two cases different?

Please help this problem.